# UIKeyboard delegate on ".?123" key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

Does anyone have an idea if we get a delegate call back from the keyboard when ".?123" button is tapped on it? We have put a customized number pad on the text keypad and want to remove it once user taps on ".?123" button to avoid duplicate keys.

Any suggestions.

Comment: I believe that it hides the keyboard and redisplays it so you can use the standard `keyboardDidHide` and `keyboardWasShown` notifications and look at they keyboard type in the notification.

Comment: No these notifications does not help. Keyboard does not go away when number key is tapped.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any notification that will give you what you want.  In fact, there isn't any public API that gives you access to the keyboard at that level.  The only way I can think of to do this, is to put a transparent button over top the .?123 key, and detect that, and then pass on the touch to the underlying button.  The button views are buried very deeply in the view hierarchy.  I used this code to first, find the keyboard, and then log the views (UIKBKeyViews) that include that button. The five views in the log below appear to be the uppercase,backspace,.?123,spacebar, and return views.

```
-(void) keyboardUp: (NSNotification*) notification { // called from UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
    UIWindow *tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]objectAtIndex:1]; 
    UIView *keyboard;
    for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES) {
           // NSLog(@"Keyboard subviews are: %@",keyboard.subviews);
            NSLog(@"%@",[[[[[[[[[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]objectAtIndex:1] contentView]subviews]lastObject]subviews]lastObject]subviews]lastObject]subviews]lastObject]subviews]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but the user might also have the international keyboard (globe key) on as well, so that needs to be detected too.

Comment: Relying on the private view hierarchy of the keyboard remaining the same is pretty fragile as well - what about the split keyboard in the iPad, or new iOS versions? I'm not saying there's a better solution, except perhaps logging this as a bug/feature request with apple.

Comment: But how the tap on the transparent button will change the keyboard view to what the tap on ".?123" does? When someone will try to tap on ".?123" the custom transparent button will get the callback, isn't it?

Comment: I think you can override - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event; in your transparent button to do what you need to do to remove your custom number pad, then call [super hitTest:point withEvent:event] to pass it on to the button below.

Comment: I do not see - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event; anywhere provided by the iOS library. Which one you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I mashed together two different methods, it should be hitTest:withEvent:, which is in the UIView class.

Comment: I tried putting a transparent button on top of keyboard put looks like you cannot draw on top of keyboard. I am drawing the button in UIKeyboardDidShowNotification but keyboard always comes on top.

Comment: How did you put it on top of the keyboard?

Comment: + for the NSLog with 13 opening brackets.